Pressure of mixture after mixing

An insulated rigid tank is divided into two compartments by a partition. One compartment contains $3 \,\text{kmol}$ of $\mathrm{O}_2$, and the other compartment contains $5 \,\text{kmol}$ of $\mathrm{CO}_2$. Both gases are initially at $25^\circ\text{C}$ and $200 \,\text{kPa}$. Now, the partition is removed, and the two gases are allowed to mix. Assuming the surroundings are at $25^\circ\text{C}$ and both gases behave as ideal gases, determine the entropy change and exergy destruction associated with the process.

The first part of the answer is given as:

Assumptions: Both gases and their mixture are ideal gases. The temperature and pressure in the tank will still be $25^\circ\text{C}$ and $200 \,\text{kPa}$ after the mixing. The entropy change of each component gas can be determined through:
$$ \Delta S_m = \sum N_i \Delta\overline{s_i} = \sum N_i \left(\overline{c_pi} \ln\frac{T_{i,2}}{T_{i,1}} - R_u\ln\frac{y_{i,2} p_{m,2}}{p_{i,2}}\right)$$
As $P_{m,2} = P_{i,2} = 200 \,\text{kPa}$. It is obvious that the entropy change is independent of the composition of the mixture in this case and that it depends on only the mole fraction of the gases of the mixture.

As you can see from the answer, they assumed that after the partition has been removed, the mixture pressure $p_{m,2}$ is exactly the same as the individual pressures $p_{\mathrm{O}_2,1}$ and $p_{\mathrm{CO}_2,1}$ before the partition was removed.
From my understanding, it then implicates that the pressure hasn't changed at all.
Why is this the case? Or am I understanding this wrongly? Is this typical for ideal gases?

Hi. Please don't use images/screenshots for text and equations. Instead, type the relevant passage using MathJax. Also, consider to name the reference.

What are the partial pressures of the two gases in the final state?

Yes, this is typical—indeed, always the case—for ideal gases. The container volumes must be $V_i=\frac{n_iRT}{P}$ for container $i$ by the ideal gas law. By the same law, the final pressure must be $P_\mathrm{final}=\frac{RT\sum n_i}{\sum V_i}=P$.

It is the partial pressure that matter in the final state, not the total pressure.

If is the final partial pressures of the components that determine the change in entropy of the mixture, not the final total pressure.  The final partial pressures of the two gases are $\frac{3}{8}(200)=75\ kPa$ and $\frac{5}{8}(200)=125\ kPa$.  So the entropy change upon mixing is $$\Delta S_m=-3R\ln{(75/200)}-5R\ln{(125/200)}$$
